# How can I reformat this Excel worksheet?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a worksheet with essentially two datasets (defined by the first column).  The worksheet looks like:

[image]
I am essentially looking to reformat this so that the values line up on the same line when the benefitAreaId, optionId, and coverageLevelId match.  I am looking for the result to be similar to the following:

[image]
In this example screenshot, the values for previous eventType are in columns A, B, and C and the values for current eventType are in D, E, and F.  I can easily populate an array with this data as follows, but I am at a loss as to how I loop through to align the data the way I need it.

```
Sub GetRangeToArray()
    Dim DirArray As Variant
    Dim NumRows As Long
    NumRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DirArray = Range("A1:D" & NumRows).Value
End Sub
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: So this is basically a transpose operation done twice, breaking on eventType transition from previous to current?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  You are correct.  With that said, I believe I have a solution now.  Instead of using arrays, I am looping through the rows checking for a match.  If it matches, I write it out to a new worksheet in the format necessary.